# How can I hide empty columns in a gridview asp.net dynamically

Tags: asp.net, linq, gridview

I am using a linq query to feed the gridview the one below:

```
var query = (from p in db.Mytable Where                   
p.Circuit_Type.Equals(drpCircuitType.SelectedItem)
&& p.Voltage >= double.Parse(Voltage)
&& p.HP >= double.Parse(HP) 
select new
    {
        p.Circuit_Type,
        p.Device1_Part_Number,
        p.Device1_Description,
        p.Device2_Part_Number,
        p.Device2_Description,
        p.Device3_Part_Number,
        p.Device4_Part_Number,
        p.Device4_Description,
        p.Min_Encl_Volume,
        p.Conditions_of_Acceptability,
        p.SCCR,
        p.Voltage_CombinationSCCR,
        p.U_Reference,
        p.Combination_Reference

    });
GridTest.DataSource = query;
GridTest.DataBind();
```

This is working so far.

so What I want is if a field of those is empty not to show that column in the gridview(hide it automatically)

Comment: Out of 100 records 1 has no Device2_Part_Number you want to hide the whole column for all records? Or do you want to hide the row?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the empty cells and hide columns. Here is an extension method.

```
public static class Extensions
    {
        public static DataGridView RemoveEmptyColumns(this DataGridView grdView)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn clm in grdView.Columns)
            {
                bool isEmpty = true;

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grdView.Rows)
                {
                    if (! string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells[clm.Index].Value.ToString()))
                    {
                        isEmpty = false;
                        break;
                    }                   
                }
                    grdView.Columns[clm.Index].Visible = isEmpty;
            }

            return grdView;
        }
    }
```

And you can call it by

```
GridTest.RemoveEmptyColumns();
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

That depends. Are the empty fields going to (A) be empty for all rows or (B) only for certain rows.

Also, in your GridView, are you using auto generated columns or did you specify them manually?

For this to work propperly it would have to be scenario A and then you could use the RowCreated event to search for and hide columns which have no data to display.

Comment: the empty fields are going to be empty for all rows(A), the whole column has to be empty and I am using Auto Generate Columns. Can you explain me with code how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Use the RowDataBound event of the grid.  in there grab the record and do you check, if you want it not to show then use

```
e.Row.Cells[index].Visible = false;
```

where index is the column index.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so assuming that the resultant set of data will return with a all items missing values for exactly the same fields and said dataset is bound to a gridview with autogenerated columns a header row then the following works (on my computer at least)

```
protected void gvproducts_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView gv = (GridView)sender;

    // iterate through the gridview's rows and hide emty cells.
    for (int r = 0; r < gv.Rows.Count; r++)
    {            
        // only interested in data rows
        if (gv.Rows[r].RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            // iterate through cells
            for (int c = 0; c < gv.Rows[r].Cells.Count; c++)
            {
                // check text content of cell
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Server.HtmlDecode(gv.Rows[r].Cells[c].Text).Trim()))
                {
                    // hide cell
                    gv.Rows[r].Cells[c].Visible = false;

                    // also hide header row's corresponding cell
                    gv.HeaderRow.Cells[c].Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

If the assumptions above fail to be true you are going to have a very wierd looking DataGrid.

You know what they say about assumptions...